# .Net Core 2.0 custom authenticantion: pass logged user id to controller

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

Our company has a custom authentication scheme that I have to use. In my .NET Core 2.0 Web API I will receive a token in each requisition and resend it to a validation service.

I'm currently using an overridden HandleAuthenticateAsync, and if the validation checks out, I need to somehow send the user id (already in hand) to the controllers. This step I was unable to get right. How do I do it?

---

```
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        string token = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        int userId = AuthService(token);
        ? // How to set up user id to be read by the controllers?
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(
                    new AuthenticationTicket(
                        new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(),
                        Scheme.Name)); // Is this right?
    }
```

Comment: You don't just "send" this info to the controllers. There's no relationship to a controller at the point of authentication. Instead, the controller has access to the principal, so therefore, the answer to your question is to set the information on the principal.